# css animate div from bottom to middle

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a div that is initially hidden. I want it to show itself and move from the bottom (outside the window) to around 90% of the window height from the top of window, before going back down outside the window, where it hides itself again. The animation works just fine, the only issue is that in larger screens, it shows up in the middle of the screen, which I don't want. How can I make come from (the bottom) outside the window in all screens?

Initially, I set the component right inside the main root div, so sa-root would be positioned absolutely, relative to the main root div. But the issue there was that sa-root would show up at the bottom of the main root div, in section 4, whereas I want it to show up in section 2. So, instead I set it in section 2.

the css I got so far:

```
#sa-root {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: -50px;
    display: flex;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
    color: #959595;
    border-radius: 43px;
    height: 42px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 27px;
    width: fit-content;
    animation-name: showandhide;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes showandhide {
    0% { bottom: calc(-10vh); visibility: visible; }
    50% { bottom: calc(8vh); }
    85% { bottom: calc(8vh); }
    100% { bottom: calc(-10vh); visibility: hidden; }
}
```

the html:

```
<div id="main">
    <section id="section1">
        //some content
    </section>
    <section id="section2">
        { showAlert && <CAlert/> }
        //some content
    </section> 
    <section id="section3">
        //some content
    </section>
    <section id="section4">
        //some content
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out all I had to do was add this to sa-root. This way, it doesn't matter where you place the component, it'll position itself absolutely relative to the window.

```
position: fixed;
```